# Python code to enumerate over all acyclic digraphs with 5 nodes

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, bayesian

So I was recently studying this course on Probabilistic Graphical Models and I wanted to try a hands-on example. In the example, I want to loop over all possible combinations (29,281) acyclic digraphs (or DAGs) and see how they fit the data.

I know that the number of all possible graphs is given by

```
from scipy.misc import comb
import numpy as np

def a(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    else:
        sum = 0
        for k in range(1,n+1):
            sum += np.power(-1,k+1)    * \
                   comb(n,k)           * \
                   np.power(2,k*(n-k)) * \
                   a(n-k)
        return sum
```

This gives us the series [A003024](https://oeis.org/A003024)

But I'd like to find the algorithm to be able to loop over all these possible graphs and not just count them.

I know there is some code available for undirected graphs, but I couldn't get them to work for me.

I'm open to any form of representation of the graph, be it a library, a custom function or a list of lists.

Example- when you have two labels, there are 3 possible graphs:

```
[[A:{}], [B:{}]]  # A    B no connection P(A,B) = P(A)P(B)
[[A:{B}], [B:{}]] # A -> B               P(A,B) = P(A)P(B|A)
[[A:{}], [B:{A}]] # A <- B               P(A,B) = P(B)P(A|B)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you want 29,281 resulting graphs, labelling must be important for you (IOW, you're not modding out by isomorphism.)  Using a brute-force approach in networkx:

```
from itertools import combinations, product
import networkx as nx

def gen_dag(num_nodes):
    all_edges = list(combinations(range(num_nodes), 2))
    for p in product([None, 1, -1], repeat=len(all_edges)):
        G = nx.DiGraph()
        G.add_nodes_from(range(num_nodes))
        edges = [edge[::edge_dir] for edge, edge_dir in zip(all_edges, p) if edge_dir]
        G.add_edges_from(edges)
        if nx.is_directed_acyclic_graph(G):
            yield G
```

which gives

```
In [75]: graphs = list(gen_dag(5))

In [76]: len(graphs)
Out[76]: 29281
```

and (for example)

```
In [79]: graphs[1234].edges()
Out[79]: OutEdgeView([(3, 1), (3, 4), (4, 0), (4, 2)])

In [80]: nx.adjacency_matrix(graphs[1234]).todense()
Out[80]: 
matrix([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 1, 0, 0]], dtype=int64)
```

Comment: I was actually contemplating this approach but I wasn't aware there was a `.is_directed_acyclic_graph()`

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to think of your graphs simply as a connection of edges (the nodes can be kept constant).

Start from numEdges = 0 (unconnected graph) and go to numEdges = numNodes - 1 (fully-connected graph). For each numEdges, simply place edges in every possible permutation.

Set your possible edges using the fully-connected graph. For five nodes for example:

```
AB
AC
AD
AE
BC
BD
BE
CD
CE
DE
```

Note the pattern: A (B, C, D, E), B (C, D, E), C(D, E), D(E)

Once you prepare your list of possible edges, it should be straightforward to place down edges according to the permutations.